# When flat submodule is direct summand?

Tags: abelian-groups, flatness

Let $M$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. And $N \subset M$ is a submodule. Assume that $N$ is flat as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Then I'm wondering if 
$$
M/N \subset M \Rightarrow N \ is \ direct \ summand \ of M
$$ 
is true. But $M/N \subset M$ means that there is an injective group homomorphism  $M/N \rightarrow M$.

Is there a counter example?

Comment: What does $M/N\subset M$ mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "an inclusion"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$M=\Bbb Q\oplus\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)$$
and let $N$ be the $\Bbb Z$ embedded in the $\Bbb Q$ factor.
Of course $N$ is flat, and $M/N\cong \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)$ but $N$ is not a direct summand of $M$.